# Is there any way to send multiple parameters to @Factory annotation in TestNG

Tags: java, csv, testng, factory

I am using @Factory annotation to call a test class and generate reports for that. I will be testing around 100 test cases using parameters 1 to 100. Is there any way I can pass all those different parameters using a .CSV sheet in @Factory annotation. It should read column wise data from .CSV and send that parameters at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full fledged example that should break down things for you.

For convenience I am using `opencsv` library.

Here's how the dependency looks like

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
  <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's what the contents of my csv file looks like:

```
name,ranking,won,lost
Undertaker,1,95,5
Hitman,2,90,10
Yokozuna,10,50,50
```

Here's how the test class looks like:

```java
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvBindByName;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {


    @CsvBindByName(column = "name")
    private String name;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ranking")
    private int ranking;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "won")
    private int matchesWon;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "lost")
    private int matchesLost;

    @Test
    public void testSuperStarName() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(name);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSuperStarRanking() {
        Assert.assertTrue(ranking != 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMatchesWon() {
        Assert.assertTrue(matchesWon > 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMatchesLost() {
        Assert.assertTrue(matchesLost > 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SampleTestClass{" +
                "superStarName='" + name + '\'' +
                ", ranking=" + ranking +
                ", matchesWon=" + matchesWon +
                ", matchesLost=" + matchesLost +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here's how the factory class would look like (This is the class you would be running)

```java
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TestFactoryProducerTest {
    @Factory
    public static Object[] produceInstances() throws IOException {
        try (
                BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("src/test/resources/62280931.csv"));
        ) {
            CsvToBean<SampleTestClass> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                    .withType(SampleTestClass.class)
                    .build();
            return csvToBean.parse().toArray(new SampleTestClass[0]);
        }
    }
}
```